# How to make vertical guide lines darker in Sublime text editor?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like the vertical guide lines little thicker. They are now light gray. I am using Sublime Text 3, build 3083. Just started today learning this editor and not able to find how to do this.

Here is screen shot. I added red markers to point to the lines I want darker.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My current preferences file has this

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Dawn.tmTheme",
    "use_tab_stops" : false,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to edit your color scheme file. To find your color scheme file, install `PackageResourceViewer` through Package Control by doing the following:

1. Go to Command Panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in `Package Control: Install Package` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type in `PackageResourceViewer` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Now that you have Package Control installed, you can install PackageResourceViewer by doing the following:

1. Go to Command Panel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Type in `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type in `Color Scheme - Default` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Type in `Dawn.tmTheme` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

Now that you're inside the file, look under the `<key>settings</key>` section. You need to add the following to the `<dict>` tag under the settings:

```
<key>guide</key>
<string>#000000</string>
<key>activeGuide</key>
<string>#000000</string>
```

The value inside that `string` tags will determine what color those lines will be. For example, I used the color `#000000` which will make it a black as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: Do you know where this file Dawn.tmTheme located on windows so I can try?

Comment: Do you have Package Control installed and do you know how to use it? If so, install the `PackageResourceViewer` package and then follow the steps that I've added to my answer.

Comment: THis is not working for me. I am using version 3, I do not even know how to install this PackageResourceViewer. I click on preferences, and see BrowsePackages... I click on it, and nothing happens. May be because I have not registered it? I just downloaded this today. I am stuck now. I searched all the folders where this is installed,  `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` and I see no such file. Also when I type ctrl-shift-P, I do not see `PackageResourceViewer:` anywhere

Comment: Go to https://packagecontrol.io/ and click `Install Now`. Copy the code snippet for the Sublime Text 3 version. Inside Sublime, type ctrl + ` to open the console. Paste the code snippet into the console and hit Enter. Once the installation is complete, restart and then follow all the steps in my edited answer. Package Control is a package manager for Sublime Text that makes it easy to install and manage plugins. The reason why you could not find your color scheme is because the file is contained in a Sublime Package which can't be accessed without something like PackageResourceViewer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But this is a very complicated editor ;)

Comment: It's actually pretty simple - you just opened the color scheme file and then made changes to it. The only reason there were so many steps was because you just installed the editor and had no plugins installed already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81762/discussion-between-saadq-and-nasser).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your settings.

```
"indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
```

Comment: thanks. I did, and also restarted the editor, but I see no change? Here is screen shot just to make sure I did it correctly ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jtcDl.png), but the vertical lines still same as before, not darker or anything else.

Comment: I think it might be the color scheme you are using. Try using a darker scheme like blackboard and see what happens. It shouldn't highlight all the indentation lines. Just the ones that are the parent of the line you are on.

Comment: I like the color scheme I have (Dawn). I prefer black text or white background, else it will be hard for me to use. My eye do not tolerate too much colors and dark background. But I just did try different ones, and the blackboard. No change really. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oPwKi.png)  and here is screen shot on the them I want to use: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdK0u.png) I'd like it little darker. I looks same as before. Is there a draw_black option to this?